# Convert java Class<> to kotlin's KClass<>

Tags: java, kotlin

like I hava a kotlin function:

```
object KotlinFunc {
    @JvmStatic
    fun create(mycls: KClass<*>) {...}
}
```

I want to invoke this function in java code, but this not working:

```
public void javaFunc() {
   KotlinFunc.create(MyClass.class)
}
```

Answer (score 24):

It is possible by using calling the `getKotlinClass` function in Java:

```
kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass(MyClass.class);
```

you can invoke your function like this:

```
kotlin.reflect.KClass<MyClass> kClass = kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass(MyClass.class);
KotlinFunc.create(kClass);
```

and make sure that `kotlin-reflect` is in your classpath, e.g.:

with Gradle Kotlin:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
    ...
}
```

with Gradle Groovy:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    ...
}
```

Comment: `kotlin-reflect` should not be required to convert java `Class<>` to kotlin `KClass<>`. `JvmClassMappingKt` is declared in `kotlin-stdlib`.

Comment: @Ilya I can't find `JvmClassMappingKt` in `kotlin-stdlib` I am sure you still need `kotlin-reflect`

Comment: @MohamedAouledIssa The fully qualified name of that class is `kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt` and it is located in `kotlin-stdlib` artifact. Note that this is how that class looks from Java code, not from Kotlin code.

Comment: The code compiles without kotlin-reflect but there is a runtime exception when it's not included, so it is required after all.

Answer (score 14):

In Kotlin `Class` [has an extension property `.kotlin`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.lang.-class/).

It is declared in `kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMapping.kt` ([source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/e23b4df519e4ec2ffcff7aefc3adf4d54d9174a9/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMapping.kt#L78)).

In Java it will look as a static method `<T> KClass<T> getKotlinClass(Class<T>)` in the class `kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt`.

Comment: I am not sure this will map java classes to kotlin classes. the trick is to  use kotlin-reflection `JavaToKotlinClassMap`

Comment: If you are talking about not converting e.g. `java.lang.String` to `kotlin.String`, the question doesn't ask for that.

Comment: "In Kotlin Class has an extension property .kotlin." - really? I am trying to use `cl.kotlin` where `cl: Class<*>` with no luck.

Comment: Here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.lang.-class/. The problem may be that it's limited to `Class<T: Any>`, so `*` won't work.

Comment: `Exception::class.java.kotlin` did the trick for me. :) 
@Alexey Romanov thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You can do it this way using the standard library:

```
KClass kotlinClass = Reflection.createKotlinClass(MyClass.class);
KotlinFunc.create(kotlinClass)
```

Comment: It's possible to do in Kotlin, so it can be invoked from Java.

Comment: You're right. I've updated the answer to use the appropriate method from `kotlin-stdlib`

Answer (score 0):

Use `KClass<Object> k = new ClassReference(myJavaClass)`.
From this commit in 2015: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/628bb774fd404a307499575fd30c7325e6660d18